# Is there a Gerrit API that can tell me if a user has a specific permission to a ref?

Tags: gerrit

I have seen the documentation for Gerrit's [check.access](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#check-access) API, but it does not seem to work at all as described when trying it out with the `gerritcodereview/gerrit:2.15.2` docker image.

For example, the documentation says that if I pass `permission`, I **must** pass a `ref`. This doesn't seem to be the case at all. I am able to POST the following body:

```
{
  "account": "admin",
  "permission": "read"
}
```

And it happily returns a `{ status: 200 }` response. The [source code for check access](https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/gerrit/blob/3ae1927b34efd50452dc4ec36a5eadbb63c114ac/java/com/google/gerrit/server/restapi/project/CheckAccess.java#L99) seems to tell me that this should not be the behaviour, so I can't understand why it works this way. The only time this API returns a `403` is if I explicitly disallow the `read` permission on a project. I cannot seem to make the check work for any other permission, like `push` for example.

All I am really trying to do is to figure out whether a given Gerrit user has a specific permission on a ref. What is the right way to get this information from Gerrit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Gerrit version are you using?

It seems the "permission" option is implemented only in master (the future release):

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#access-check-input

In the latest release (2.15.3) documentation there's no "permission" option:

https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.15.3/rest-api-projects.html#access-check-input

Comment: That explains it. I tried with 2.15.2 and 2.15.3. I hadn't realized that the first URL is actually documentation for `master`. Thanks!

Comment: A quick follow up, if you don't mind... does this mean that there is no _easy_ way in 2.15.3 to answer the permissions question about a user?

Comment: I don't think so... there's also the "gerrit ls-user-refs" command (https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-ls-user-refs.html) but it only shows the read permissions too.